# Point Domain to my vServer

Tags: dns, debian

I've a problem with my vServer. I own two Domains and want to point them to my new vServer.

Now i want to edit the hosts-file and make an entry for the new Domains.

I changed the "sites-available" entry:

/etc/apache2/sites-available

and added one file with my configurations:

```
<VirtualHost * >
# Anmerkung: Default Domain muss vorhanden sein
ServerAdmin domainname@me.com
ServerName www.domainname.de
ServerAlias domainname.de
# Anmerkung: Sicherstellung der Erreichbarkeit bei Schreibfehlern; *Domain –> Problem mit Subdomains
DocumentRoot /var/www/
# Pfad zu lokalen Verzeichnis unserer Debian Etch Webseite :-)
<Directory /var/www/>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Options -Indexes
# option = keine Auflistungvon Verzeichnissen im Browser
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've linked the file with a2ensite and restartet apache. But when i type www.domainname.de in the browser, nothing happens.

My host-file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
83.169.2.78 lvps83-169-2-78.dedicated.hosteurope.de lvps83-169-2-78
```

I've searched for one week now, and everywhere, in every tutorial: only make a new file with the domainname, link it, restart apache and that's it.

Where is the problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the DNS A records to your servers public IP address.  Assuming you have DNS services provided by the company you bought the domains through, go to their control panel and look there.

Comment: I have no control panel. I want to do it all via terminal and ssh. Or is it too difficutl for "normal IT guys" to configure Domains like that?

Comment: You say you "own" 2 domains - who did you buy these from?

Comment: hosteurope.de. I configured them now via Parallels Power Panel... but no success...contacted the support for further help. Is there ANY GOOD explanation about domains and dns servers? i'm no noob, but every time i set up a vserver there are problems with the domains...

Comment: you sound like a noob a bit.. the domains need to be pointed using DNS to your servers IP

Comment: this is done via a DNS server, normally provided by your domain registrar, if not then the DNS server is specified by your domain registrar, have you done this at your domain registrar?